Jmeter Prometheus Distributed Testing Using Prometheus Listener
Hi even I am facing same issue. I have a very basic setup where 1 master jmeter machine is connected to 2 child jmeter machines. I want to run test using all 4 jmeter slave machines. Prometheus is configured on master machines now when I run a test o my one master machine I am able to see data in Prometheus but if I try to run from jmeter child/ slave machine the test runs fine but I am unable to see any metrics. I am unable to launch http://<machine-ip/hostnamr>:9270/metrics what settings I am missing.
I tried adding Prometheus.ip and Prometheus.port in slave machines jmeter properties. Do I have to add anything else.

Please clarify.   Are you using prometheus to monitor the health of your load generators, your application under test, or both?
